# Change opacity of image using input slider. JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, webkit, opacity

I am trying to change the image opacity using the -webkit-filter in jquery. What my code is doing here is it gets the value from the input type= range and based on that value it change the opacity if the image:

```
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {
    var opacitySet = $('#slider').val();
    $('#imgSlector').css('-webkit-filter', 'opacity('${opacitySet}%')'); 
    
});
```

Please help me here it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

correct code: $('#myImg').css("filter", `opacity(${opacitySet}%)`);

you don't need these ' like opacity('82%');
delete ' like filter: opacity(82%);